# What is this probe on the Airbus A330 engine nacelle?

Tags: feature-identification, turbofan, airbus-a330

[image: RR Trent engine on A330neo]

What is the purpose of the little probe seen under the A330neo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the Rolls-Royce TRENT 7XX-8XX and RB-221-5XX, that is the "Engine Breather Outlet".

[image]

Cite: https://www.scribd.com/doc/283987010/A330-ATA-71-80-RR-Trent-700-L3-e-pdf# (page 44)

Possibly relevant: [What is the function of the protruding outlet on the Trent XWB?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35000/what-is-the-function-of-the-protruding-outlet-on-the-trent-xwb)

Comment: So this would be almost similar to the long breather tube on the 737 CFM56.